# Lucene: How to index ngrams and search in them

Tags: search, lucene, partial, n-gram

I guess the only way to search for partial words and phrases in Lucene is by using ngramtokenizer. If there are any other ways then please suggest. I am a C# programmer and I am new to lucene and java programming. I am using Eclipse IDE and Lucene 5.3.0. I managed to create lucene index of a text file and search in it with standardanalyzer and englishanalyzer, but I am running into errors when indexing ngram tokens. I followed a few examples online and none of them work. I need a simple straightforward example of how to create index and search in it for partial words and phrases using ngrams in lucene 5.3.0. I hope, the experts here can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some details, your code, exactly what's wrong with your code, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured out that I hadn't implemented the createComponents method properly. It works now.